# Uploading mp4 from Android phone to Spring server results in file missing a few hundred bytes if bigger than 2MB

Tags: java, android, spring, xamarin.forms, file-upload

I have been trying to upload to a Java Spring server running on my laptop, using an app written in Xamarin forms, using a physical Redmi Android device.

But when I send out the multi-part request, if it is bigger than about 2MB, the file loses a few hundred bytes by the time it reaches the server.

For example, the original video file has 8,268,891 bytes. Sometimes the file that reaches the server will have 8,267,175 and sometimes 8,269,279 or some other random number.

I don't know if it's related to my Xamarin code, because this seems to happen whether I use multi-part requests or send it as a base64 string in a request.

But just in case, here is my multi-part Xamarin code

```
               var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var videoBytes = new ByteArrayContent(file.GetStream().ToByteArray());
                multipartContent.Add(videoBytes, "file", file.Path.FileName());
                multipartContent.Add(new StringContent(serializedRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "request");

                content = multipartContent;
            }

            switch (type)
            {
                case RequestType.Post:
                    result = await client.PostAsync(_siteUrl + apiPath, content, cancellationToken);
                    break;
```

And my controller on the Spring server

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { RequestMappingConstants.MOBILE + RequestMappingConstants.UPLOAD + RequestMappingConstants.UPLOAD_VIDEO }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public @ResponseBody VideoUploadResponse uploadVideo(@RequestPart(value="request") VideoUploadRequest request, @RequestPart(value="file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
      LOG.info("Inside video upload");
      return uploadService.uploadWelcomeVideo(request, file, httpRequest);
```

}

Also, my settings on the server:

```
multipart.maxFileSize= 100MB
multipart.maxRequestSize= 100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true 
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB 
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=215MB 
spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily=false
```

Again, this happens as long as the video file exceeds about 2MB. The corrupted file that reaches the server is unplayable.
The server and client are running on the same wi-fi network.

I would be very grateful if you could help.

Comment: What is that file-size-treshold standing for?

Comment: In the deferred file output stream, if multi-part file gets to be more than 2KB, then save it as a file. If less, then keep it in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be something wrong with my laptop or wireless network that was causing packet loss. Nothing to do with the code, as it was working when I tried it on a production server

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you also need to adjust the Tomcat and/or Jetty (as appropriate) settings:

```
server.jetty.max-http-form-post-size: 100MB                                      
                                                                                
server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size: 100MB                                     
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size: -1
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that didn't fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry: What version of Spring Boot are you running?  (The property names changed with 2.1.x and were different before.)

Comment: 2.0.3. The properties that compiled for my spring server were like this:
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size= 100000000                               
server.tomcat.max-http-header-size=10000.
Your answer is still useful so giving it +1

Comment: I'm glad it helped -- the property names changed (as you determined)